# Unable to extend some users' access tokens for our application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

We've been having an issue where some of our users only receive shortlived access tokens even after going through the server side oauth flow and extending the token.  After doing a bit of debugging, I've realized this happens for our application in production, but not for any of my test apps.  Is it possible Facebook is limiting our application for some reason (perhaps because of spam reports?)

As a way to test this out, I've created a test utility which describes our application's oauth process and the responses received from Facebook.

1. Go here: [Buffer Facebook OAuth Test utility](https://bufferapp.com/oauth/facebook/test)
2. Login with test facebook user:

   ```
       username: ssadasivan@yahoo.com
       password: thisisabadpassword
   ```
3. Review the oauth flow.

As a reference, this is the output we receive for this utility: http://cl.ly/image/0U273e163o2o

Unfortunately the response from Facebook regarding our reports haven't been as helpful as we  hoped.

[Reported issue with test utility](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/608785145799853)

[Reported issue where solution did not resolve the issue](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/572944616072765)

[Related Issue](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/454002448026546)

Any insight here would be greatly appreciated :).

Comment: AFAIK you need to exchange the just granted acces_token against a so called "long lived token". We're doing that in any case and immediately all the time getting an access token from FB. Before, we considered similar problems. https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: forget my comment, I've seen from the screenshots that you're already doing that. Fine. Recently we had a 500 Server error on that endpoint for a couple of days, so I think they are still fiddling around with this?

Comment: Did you try the steps as written on [this bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/572944616072765)

Comment: I believe my answer on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/572944616072765 is correct - do you have any reason to believe it isn't?

Comment: Hi @igy, thanks so much for your response and work here in helping!  It means a lot to us that you're involved. I have tried the solution provided in that ticket quite a few times with no luck, (calling DELETE on /me/permissions before going through the flow again).  One thing to note is the example provided here uses a user who has not authenticated before the deprecation of offline_access. When using a different application with the same flow, we get the long lived token as expected.  Do let me know if you need any other information from me to help reproduce this.

Answer (score 0):

We have had similar problems as well, but in using their javascript API. 
The access token acting weirdly in some cases. (only lasts a few seconds)
The work around we end up using is do a log-in status check before any FB api call like:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
  //do your thing
}
```

I dont know how is your backend code work.

The basic idea is keep current facebook session live even though your access token is still valid.
check its new endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#extend_token

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```